# tomcat server application path problem

Tags: java, url, tomcat, jakarta-ee, path

i use tomcat 6 for production. i have a web app deployed on this server called: app.war
   it has a url : test.org.

every time when i undeploy app.war and redeploy it this path won't work any more
   http://test.org/home

but this url always work:  http://test.org/app/home.

to make the first url work, i need to restart the tomcat server.

i wonder why when i redeploy the app.war the url http://test.org/home does not work.

if there a way to make it always work without restarting the server?
   i don't want the application name to be included in the url

Thanks

Comment: Did you modify ROOT.xml to make the `app.war` WAR file the ROOT Context? It sounds like the binding is removed when you undeploy but not re-created when you redeploy.

Comment: what is root.xml. where is root.xml located?

Comment: Usually in the configuration folder: look in your `conf/Catalina/localhost/` folder.

Comment: i checked the conf/Catalina, there are several folders in the conf/Catalina, each folder is responding to one host directives defined in the server.xml files. the folder 134.xx.xxx.xx  is the app.war folder, so i create a root.xml in that folder. is that right? what content i need to put in

Answer (score 1):

This has no simple answer, as there are many components involved. You should isolate the problem. For instance, you could start removing test.org domain mapping, ensuring that there's no component possibly caching the output and so on.

And then after you had isolated Tomcat from anything else, if the problem persist, you could state that this is a Tomcat problem.

So please (pleeeeeeease) refine your question when you have done a couple of these steps so the SO community can help you.

Sorry for the long response.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your app.xml in ${TOMCAT_HOME}/conf/Catalina/localhost . Whe you try to redeploy this file might get deleted and gets recreated causing you the problem.

Comment: thanks. is there a way not to delete this file when redeploy?

Answer (score 0):

In your war file try creating a folder META-INF at the top level (in the same directory as WEB-INF) and creating a file `context.xml` in the META-INF folder. In `context.xml` put this:

```
<Context path="" reloadable="true">
</Context>
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: what is the right way to re-deploy a war without causing this problem

Comment: I've personally never seen the default route broken when you redeploy: I'm assuming the `context.xml` file is the source, but you might have another issue. After you redeploy verify that the `context.xml` is getting copied to the conf folder (this can be disabled, depending on your Tomcat config).